# Use of CSS classes in editor-blocks.css file

Tags: css, block-editor

Checking the `editor-blocks.css` file found in some themes, I see the following CSS classes added before some of the individual block classes:

```
.edit-post-visual-editor
.editor-block-list__layout
.editor-block-list__block
.block-library-list
```

An example:

```
.editor-block-list__block .wp-block-latest-comments {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

And then others, don't have them:

```
.wp-block-quote.is-large,
.wp-block-quote.is-style-large {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 0.8em 0.8em;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;    
}
```

What's the use of these CSS classes? Which elements in the block editor do they target? Why do some of the block CSS classes have them added before and why others don't? Are they really necessary? Why some themes have an `editor-blocks.css` file and a `blocks.css` file and why others just the `blocks.css` one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd guess so they can have different styles in the editor or in the block selection list than they have on the live site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, these are the conclusions I reached after studying the block editor for some time.

Both `.editor-block-list__layout` and `.editor-block-list__block` classes are deprecated since WordPress 5.4 and have been renamed to `.block-editor-block-list__layout` and `.block-editor-block-list__block`, respectively. The `.block-editor-block-list__layout` class targets all the blocks found in the post content and `.block-editor-block-list__block` class targets individual block types in the post content, so the latter is equivalent to using the specific `.wp-block-***` classes.

I have not seen the `.block-library-list` class used anywhere in the block editor, so I assume it makes no sense targeting it.

Finally, the `.edit-post-visual-editor` class targets the whole block editor.

In summary, in the most recent versions of WordPress (5.4 onwards) it's safe to just use the `.wp-block-***` classes to style individual block types in the block editor.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the editor source code: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg does not show much results. I suggest search the theme source code these classes to see where they are applied. (If you press . while viewing the code on github you will get a VSCode editor)

[`register_block_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/) is used to add the block date in WordPress. Typically with these arguments:

```php
 register_block_type( 'custom-plugin/custom-block', array(
        'editor_script' => 'editor-script.js',
        'editor_style'  => 'editor-style.css',
        'style'         => 'frontend.css',
    ) );
```

`editor_script` and `editor_style` add files to editor admin. `style` is meant to add CSS to frontend.

What documentation does not mention is that `style` is also loaded in backend. So it is possible those theme are using one file for bother backend and frontend to minimize the code they write.

Answer (score -1):

The `editor-block-list__block` class in only rendered in the Gutenberg editor, while the `wp-block-[blockname]` class is rendered on both the front end and the editor. So classes prepended with `editor-block-list__block` are targeting the backend only.